# Is it possible that __destruct is called before __construct is finished?

Tags: php, constructor, destructor

I have a project [leash](https://github.com/jcubic/leash) and in JSON-RPC service I'm writing to a file in __destruct, but sometimes the config file is cleared (it look like this `{"sessions":[],"users":[]}`) it happen from time to time and also when I refresh the page fast before ajax request is finished, it look like the __constructor didn't finished before __destruct is called, I have code like this:

```
class Service {
    protected $config_file;
    protected $config;
    const password_hash = 'h'; // function use for password on installation
    const password_regex = '/([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*):(.*)/';

    function __construct($config_file, $path) {
        $this->path = $path;
        $this->config_file = $config_file;
        $full_path = $path . "/" . $this->config_file;
        if (file_exists($full_path)) {
            try {
                $this->config = json_decode(file_get_contents($full_path));
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->config = new stdClass();
            }
            // it had no write permission when first created while testing
            if (!is_writable($full_path)) {
                chmod($full_path, 0664);
            }
        } else {
            $this->config = new stdClass();
        }
        if (!isset($this->config->sessions) || !is_array($this->config->sessions)) {
            $this->config->sessions = array();
        } else {
            $this->config->sessions = array_map(function($session) {
                return Session::cast($session);
            }, array_filter($this->config->sessions, function($session){
                return isset($session->token) && isset($session->username);
            }));
        }
        if (!isset($this->config->users) || !is_array($this->config->sessions)) {
            $this->config->users = array();
        }
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function __destruct() {
        $path = $this->path . "/" . $this->config_file;
        $this->__write($path, json_encode($this->config));
    }
```

I have other methods that modify config object like `login` that add new session to `$this->config->sessions` array. [Here is full file](https://github.com/jcubic/leash/blob/master/lib/Service.php)

I've tried to add flag `$this->corrupted` that's set to true when I've get exception but it didn't fix the issue, it must be something with time of `__destruct` being called.

I've also try to add flag `$this->safe_to_save` that get set to true in last line of constructor but that also didn't work. What may be the problem?

Comment: It's far more likely that you've hit a case where `$this->config = new stdClass();` is called. `__destruct` can only be called to destroy objects, and an object is only created if the __construct was successfully completed. Try adding some logging code in that branch that hides the exception.